# k8s deployment is not scaling on eks cluster too many pods

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm still a noob, so go gentle on me please!

I have an eks cluster running with this node group configs:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "this" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.this.name
  node_group_name = local.cluster_name
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_node.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.this.*.id
  instance_types  = ["t2.micro"]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 4
    min_size     = 2
  }

  # Optional: Allow external changes without Terraform plan difference
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [scaling_config[0].desired_size]
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks_AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}
```

my scaling configs are:

```
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 4
    min_size     = 2
  }
```

and I successfully can deploy `2` nginx replicas with the following configs:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx"
    labels = {
      App = "Nginx"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 2
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = "Nginx"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = "Nginx"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.7.8"
          name  = "nginx"

          port {
            container_port = 80
          }

          resources {
            limits = {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests = {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when I scale my replicas to `4` the pods are created but in a pending state with the following reason:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  18s (x2 over 108s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods.
```

I tried ignoring `desired_size` in `scaling_config` but didn't help to resolve the issue.

I believe I'm missing a crucial understanding working with scaling_config and the scaling group that it creates and k8s deployment replicas. Any guidance to help me understand what's going on, will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot In advance.

https://github.com/ehabshaaban/deploy-nginx/tree/eks

Comment: K8s doesn't autoscale on its own. You must install the cluster-autoscaler. See the EKS docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html

Answer (score 7):

according to the message `0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods.`, you can find the node can not be placed any pods. In EKS, the number of max pods could be placed in the node would based on several things `instance type` & `cni`. By default, you can refer this document [eni-max-pod](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt)

To solve your issue, you can increase the `desired_size` from 2 to 3. So the pods would be placed to the new nodes.

Comment: I updated desired_size to 3 and now have 4 pods running. thanks!